# Default CSS always takes effect not matter if i wrtie specific CSS for some element

Tags: css, angular, nativescript

I am building an android application using Angular Nativescript version 6.4.1.
In my root folder, I have a "app.css" file in which I wrote

```
Label{
    color: black;
}
```

In order to set all of the colors of the label to black as default. The problem is that this color stays no matter even when I want to change it for a specific label. Even I type in the label `"color: white"` it still has the black color.
If i create a `<Label text="some text" color="white"></Label>` the color of the text will be black

Answer (score 0):

It has an error in the label:

`<Label text"some text" color="white"></Label>`

to

`<Label text="some text" color="white"></Label>`

It should work

Comment: This is just a typo, its not the problem